# Update with a With and Cross Apply Statement

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, sql-update, cross-apply

I have this piece of code it pulls pricing for a given order and season by `perf_type/zone_no`.

In my original code I had `@season_no` as a local single variable. This worked magically.

```
UPDATE p
SET price = x.Price
FROM #Prices p
with 
CROSS APPLY  
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.LFT_GET_PRICES_Seasonal(@season_no, order_dt) udf
    WHERE udf.perf_type = p.perf_type AND udf.zone_no = p.zone_no
) x
```

Now we're trying to modify the code to work on multiple seasons. We have this piece of code earlier in our code.

```
select season_no from @season_table
```

I'm not sure how to consolidate the two.

```
with season_alias as (select season_no from @season_table)
```

but I don't know how to consolidate the two. How do I pass to my cross apply function the unique season_no from my `@season_table` that corresponds to each order. Can i do that?

What I need to do is replace the `@season_no` standalone single local variable, with the select statement from `@season_table` and i'm not sure how to do this.

***I can't adjust the function, not for this project***

Comment: I don't see what your first code fragment has to do with either of the other two, and after reading your question more than once, I still have no idea what you're trying to do or what you're asking.

Comment: @TabAlleman  I need to replace `@season_no` in my first code ( a single standalone variable) with a value pulled from a select statement from `@season_table`.

Comment: A single value?   Which value?

Comment: @TabAlleman in my update statement there is a `@season_no` passed to the function. That value needs to be replaced with the season_no coming from `@season_table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given enough information to be specific, but I can tell you in general that you can use a correlated sub-query and replace this:

```
FROM dbo.LFT_GET_PRICES_Seasonal(@season_no, order_dt) udf
```

with something like this:

```
FROM dbo.LFT_GET_PRICES_Seasonal((SELECT TOP 1 season_no FROM @season_table WHERE something=somethingelse), order_dt) udf
```

Comment: apologies for the lack of clarity. Only follow up question is why top 1? How do I match the correct @season_no to the season value in the #prices table

Comment: Top 1 because the subquery must return a single value for each row in the outer query.   How to match the correct value is what you have not given us enough information to tell you.

Comment: It seems you are right thought, it just occurred to me that since i have season_no in my #prices table i can just pass that value instead of joining on any kind of localized extra tables.